# My display module doesn't display (Python 2.7)

Tags: python

This is for homework. This particular school offers 0 assistance and the professor is less than helpful. I am just looking for guidance as to why this code isn't working. I *have* to use Python 2.7. When I run the program it asks me to enter the appropriate amount of pints but then does nothing.

```
# This program finds the average number of pints collected, the highest amount, and the lowest amount

# Lab 9-4 Blood drive

#the main function
def main():
    endProgram = 'no'
  print
  while endProgram == 'no':
    print
    # declare variables
    pints = [0] * 7
    totalPints = 0
    averagePints = 0
    highPints = 0
    lowPints = 0


    # function calls
    pints = getPints(pints)
    totalPints = getTotal(pints, totalPints)
    averagePints = getAverage(totalPints, averagePints)
    highPints = getHigh(pints, highPints)
    lowPints = getLow(pints, lowPints)
    displayInfo(averagePints, highPints, lowPints)

    endProgram = raw_input('Do you want to end program? (Enter no or yes): ')
    while not (endProgram == 'yes' or endProgram == 'no'):
      print 'Please enter a yes or no'
      endProgram = raw_input('Do you want to end program? (Enter no or yes): ')

#the getPints function
def getPints(pints):
  counter = 0
  while counter < 7:
      pints[counter] = input('Enter pints collected: ')
      counter = counter + 1
  return pints

#the getTotal function
def getTotal(pints, totalPints):
    counter = 0
    while counter < 7:
        totalPints = totalPints + pints[counter]
        counter = counter + 1
    return totalPints

#the getAverage function
def getAverage(totalPints, averagePints):
    averagePints = totalPints / 7
    return averagePints

#the getHigh function
def getHigh(pints, highPints):
    highPints = pints[0]
    counter = 1
    while counter < 7:
        if pints[counter] > highPints:
            highPints = pints[counter]
            counter = counter + 1
    return highPints



#the getLow function
def getLow(pints, lowPints):
    lowPints = pints[0]
    counter = 1
    while counter < 7:
        if pints[counter] < lowPints:
            lowPints = pints[counter]
            counter = counter + 1
    return lowPints

#the displayInfo function
def displayInfo(averagePints, highPints, lowPints):
    print "The average number of pints donated is ", averagePints
    print "The highest pints donated is ", highPints
    print "The lowest pints donated is ", lowPints

# calls main
main()
```

Comment: Hint: in `getHigh` and `getLow`, take a look at the `while` loop, especially the indentation level of `counter = counter + 1`. Depending on the values in `pints`, what happens?

Comment: Does your school tell you not to use `for` loops? Also don't use yes or no as values for `endProgram`. If you want a boolean use a boolean.

Comment: Your indents are off, please edit your question! It is impossible to debug python code unless it is properly indented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an infinite loop in function `getLow()` because `counter` is incremented only when the current value is less than the previous value. e.g. entering values `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7` will result in an infinite loop, however, the loop will terminate if you entered `7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1`.

Function `getHigh()` has a similar problem, but the values must be ascending if the infinite loop is to be avoided. Note that one of `getLow()` or `getHigh()` will always produce a loop in your code.

Hint: look at using Python's `min()` and `max()` functions.

Comment: Other improvements beyond the bug: 1) `sum`, 2) `len` instead of hard-coding the length, 3) the signatures of the functions don't need the return values as parameters, 4) should `getAverage` be an integer division.